# Apache Nifi - ConvertJSONtoSQL processor

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

I installed everything on Windows:

```
1- MySQL
2- Apache Nifi
```

My flow goes fine until it reaches the **`ConvertJSONtoSQL`** process
attached error.

The purpose of the flow is:

- Get a **.csv** file
- Convert it to JSON format
- Convert JSON to SQL
- Dump the result to a table

The illustration of the current flow :

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, the question was why it shows me that warn. But yesterday, after a while, I figured out that was because I have to insert a username and password in one of the box inside the processor. 
Thans anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the question was why it shows me that warn. But yesterday, after a while, I figured out that was because I have to insert a username and password in one of the box inside the processor.